# Como listar uma query sem saber o que vai ser retornado?

Tags: php, mysql

Nesse exemplo eu defini alguns atributos a serem mostrados, mas no jogo eu não sei quais devo mostrar porque o usuário é quem vai fazer a consulta.

```
<?php 
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry_result)){?>
   <tr>
     <td><?= $row[id_funcionario]?></td>
     <td><?= $row[end_funcionario]?></td>
     <td><?= $row[nome_funcionario]?></td>
   </tr>

<?php } ?>
```

Como eu faço pra listar essa **$qry_result** na tabela sem saber o que vai ser retornado?

Exemplo: No meu Jogo de SQL tem um campo onde o usuário digita a instrução SQL. Ele pode digitar por exemplo `select * from funcionarios`. Como eu mostro as informações na tabela sem saber o que ele vai digitar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pra mostrar os resultados, basta isso:

```
<?php
   while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($qry_result, MYSQL_NUM) ) {
      echo '<tr>';
      foreach($row as $item) {
         echo '<td>';
         echo htmlentities( $item );
         echo '</td>';
      }
      echo "</tr>\n";
   }
?>
```

Lembrando que você precisa limitar os privilégios de acesso do usuário, senão ele vai fazer muito mais do que dar `SELECT` onde você imagina. Dá pra pensar desde um `DROP TABLE` até uma consulta à sua tabela de senhas.

### Versão com títulos:

```
<?php
   $primeira = true;
   while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($qry_result, MYSQL_ASSOC) ) {
      if ($primeira ) {
         echo '<tr>';
         foreach($row as $titulo => $item) {
            echo '<th>';
            echo htmlentities( $titulo );
            echo '</th>';
         }
         echo '</tr>';
         $primeira = false;
      }
      echo '<tr>';
      foreach($row as $item) {
         echo '<td>';
         echo htmlentities( $item );
         echo '</td>';
      }
      echo "</tr>\n";
   }
?>
```